# « Aller au bar » ou « aller dans les bars »?

Tags: choix-de-mot, prépositions, formulation-idiomatique, formulation, reformulation

Les gens d’aujourd’hui vont de moins en moins

…au bar pour séduire car ils le font à partir d’applications mobiles sur leur portable. Ils invitent aussi leurs amis à boire chez eux ou sortent faire la fête chez ces derniers.

…dans les bars pour séduire car ils le font à partir d’applications mobiles sur leur téléphone.  Ils invitent aussi leurs amis à boire chez eux ou sortent faire la fête chez ces derniers.

D’autres variantes à proposer?

Comment: La première proposition (« aller au bar ») me parait plus idiomatique. L’autre reste tout à fait correcte et compréhensible.

Comment: Quand *on va dans un bar*, on peut *aller* [s'accouder] *au bar* pour savourer sa boisson préférée et discuter avec autrui, quelque soit l'origine de la rencontre.

Comment: @Personne Ce serait donc plus idiomatique d’écrire « dans les bars » si on fait référence à l’établissement et non pas au comptoir?

Comment: Mais il faut aussi dire que le verbe « aller » se construit le plus souvent avec la préposition « à »: je m’en vais à l’épicerie, à la boulangerie, au dépanneur (sous-entendu du coin, du quartier, du voisinage).

Comment: @Thérèse … tout à fait, « faire le tour des bars/boites de nuit », « chercher un bar/une boite où aller/passer la soirée », c'est dans cette idée. On règle l'addition au comptoir dans les brasseries et bistros, … on ne peut donc pas aller dans le comptoir/bar.

Comment: Je me demande pourquoi nous avons la propension de dire  « est-ce qu’on va au bar », quel que soit celui qu’on a dans l’idée, quel que soit le nombre de bars se trouvant dans la ville où nous sommes, qu’il soit dans le voisinage de l’endroit où nous nous trouvons ou plus loin.

Comment: En tout cas c’est le cas dans ma région mes amis disent souvent « est-ce qu’on va au bar » sans qu’il soit question d’un bar en particulier, peu importe lequel, qu’on le fréquente souvent ou non.

Comment: J’imagine qu’il doit s’agir d’un français relâché, celui qu’on emploie entre proches et entre amis en manière de simplification.

Comment: « Aller au bar » *sans qu’il soit question d’un bar en particulier*, n'est pas vraiment en usage dans l'hexagone, on répondra alors « Lequel ? » — On entendra plutôt : « On va trouver/chercher un bar/une boite ce soir ou on fait autre chose ? »

Answer (score 1):

"Aller au coiffeur", "Aller au bar", sont à proscrire absolument. Vous allez chez le coiffeur, vous irez dans un bar, vous fréquenterez les bars.

Néanmoins cette tournure "aller au bar", bien qu'inélégante et sans doute incorrecte capture quelque chose de plus qu'"aller dans un bar" : "aller au bar" revient à considérer l'activité qui consiste à aller dans un bar comme indifférenciée relativement au choix du bar en question, cela devient une activité générique, répertoriée par cette expression comme une activité humaine essentielle, comme manger, dormir et bien d'autres choses.

Il me semble nécessaire d'ajouter un non-dit assez important à mon avis, qui ne figure dans aucun des commentaires ci-dessous. Lorsque je dis que l'expression "aller au coiffeur" est à bannir absolument, c'est bien parce qu'elle déclasse celui qui l'emploie à un point tel qu'il risque de ne jamais s'en remettre dans un cercle social donné. Non contente d'être fautive, inélégante, l'expression "aller au coiffeur" agira contre vous de manière durable et irrémédiable, vous fermera les portes de tout cercle social modérément évolué : n'employez jamais cette expression, elle constitue, à tort ou à raison, l'exemple prototypique de l'expression fautive synonyme d'inculture et de grossièreté.

Comment: [*Aucune règle grammaticale n’est enfreinte lorsqu’on utilise la préposition « à » associée à des noms de métiers dont l’activité s’exerce à des endroits destinés à un usage commercial ou professionnel. C’est même le contraire : le sens de la préposition « chez » se retrouve fortement malmené lorsqu’on l’utilise pour désigner des endroits qui ne servent de domicile à personne. Il paraît bien plus logique et clair de dire « je vais au coiffeur » et « je vais chez mamie ».*](https://theconversation.com/aller-chez-le-coiffeur-mais-aller-aux-putes-ce-que-revele-lusage-des-prepositions-114557)

Comment: Pas trop d'accord, pour ma part. En tout cas, si "Aller au coiffeur" semble bizarre, "Aller au bar" est parfaitement idiomatique.

Comment: @XouDo *Bizarre* est exagéré alors que tout le monde a commencé par le dire naturellement et ce n'est que sous la pression de prescriptivistes et malheureusement d'enseignants que le dogme relativement récent *aller chez le coiffeur* perdure.

Comment: @XouDo *Enfin le duc relève son front, **va au roi**, lui prend la main, et le mène à pas lents devant le plus ancien des portraits, celui qui commence la galerie à droite du spectateur.* Victor Hugo, *Hernani*. 1830.

Comment: @CrissyFroth-Seapickle Je ne trouve pas le ton de l'article en question prétentieux. Il y a bien sûr de la provocation (*aller aux putes*) mais c'est pour moi de l'humour. *Aller chez le coiffeur* n'est pas rejeté, c'est le rejet d'aller *au coiffeur* qui est remis en question.